# uWSGI worker dying too fast when setting gevent parameter (to 1000)

Tags: flask, flask-socketio

I have a Flask + Flask-SocketIO installed, and when I run the Flask app via uWSGI it works great, but as soon as I add the `gevent` parameter, the workers starts to die and restart in a loop:

```
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x55a8243b97f0 pid: 11929 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 11929)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 11931, cores: 1000)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 11932, cores: 1000)
*** running gevent loop engine [addr:0x55a823adbe70] ***
DAMN ! worker 1 (pid: 11931) died :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 11933)
DAMN ! worker 2 (pid: 11932) died :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 2 (new pid: 11934)
*** running gevent loop engine [addr:0x55a823adbe70] ***
DAMN ! worker 1 (pid: 11933) died :( trying respawn ...
worker respawning too fast !!! i have to sleep a bit (2 seconds)...
Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 11944)
DAMN ! worker 2 (pid: 11934) died :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 2 (new pid: 11945)
*** running gevent loop engine [addr:0x55a823adbe70] ***
DAMN ! worker 1 (pid: 11944) died :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 11946)
DAMN ! worker 2 (pid: 11945) died :( trying respawn ...
worker respawning too fast !!! i have to sleep a bit (2 seconds)...
*** running gevent loop engine [addr:0x55a823adbe70] ***
Respawned uWSGI worker 2 (new pid: 11947)
DAMN ! worker 1 (pid: 11946) died :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 11948)
*** running gevent loop engine [addr:0x55a823adbe70] ***
DAMN ! worker 2 (pid: 11947) died :( trying respawn ...
Respawned uWSGI worker 2 (new pid: 11949)
DAMN ! worker 1 (pid: 11948) died :( trying respawn ...
worker respawning too fast !!! i have to sleep a bit (2 seconds)...
^CSIGINT/SIGQUIT received...killing workers...
Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 11950)
worker 2 buried after 0 seconds
*** running gevent loop engine [addr:0x55a823adbe70] ***
```

This is my uWSGI config (yml):

```
uwsgi:
  socket: /var/www/myapp/uwsgi.sock
  master: true
  http-websockets: true
  # gevent: 1000
  processes: 2
  uid: cx42
  gid: cx42
  chmod-socket: 666
  vacuum: true
  wsgi-file: /var/www/myapp/www/wsgi.py
  callable: app
  virtualenv: /var/www/myapp/env/
  pythonpath: /var/www/myapp/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages
  pythonpath: /var/www/myapp/www/
  post-buffering: 8192
  touch-reload: /var/www/myapp/reloaded
  ignore-sigpipe = true
  ignore-write-errors = true
  disable-write-exception = true
```

And a simplified version of my app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO()
socketio.init_app(app)

# All the code ...
```

uwsgi is locally installed via pip and gevent too.

Comment: Which Python version are you using? I have seen issues (not same as yours though) with 3.8 + uwsgi + gevent. Same set up worked okay with Python 3.7.

Comment: I have Python 3.5.3. (I finally moved to Gunicorn, worked straight out of the box ...)